# Lua math.random at coordinates

Tags: lua, autotouch

I'm trying to check a color on the screen, if the color returns with my predetermined string then I want to tap at the variables I've set at the start of the program.

```
math.randomseed(os.time())
xvar = (math.random(100) + 300)
yvar = (math.random(100) + 560)

touch = function()
local color = getColor(300,560)
if color == 16711422 then
tap(xvar ..','.. yvar)
else 
usleep(5000000)
collectgarbage()
touch()
end
end

touch()
```

When I run this where the color should be I get an alarm:

/Applications/AutoTouch.app/Extensions.lua:105: bad argument #2 to 'touchDown' (number expected, got string)

I know my language is shoddy, I'm still learning the fine print. And at times a lot of my faults just come straight from invalid structure.

The proper code is tap(x,y).
I just assumed I could input the global variable I've already noted earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're implementing `tap` with the code provided [in the docs](http://autotouch.me/server/doc/en.html). In that case, `tap` is a function that takes two numeric arguments - the X coordinate and the Y coordinate of the position to tap. You're passing it one string string, which is the concatenation of the X coordinate, a comma, and a Y coordinate.

Change `tap(xvar ..','.. yvar)` to `tap(xvar, yvar)`

Comment: Yes, I learned after some combing through help that using quotes only tells the program to read it as text. But in code a comma is not really a comma I guess. Can be hard to understand when you're first learning. But this worked, thank you!